# Interpolating heights in DEM using ArcGIS API's in C#

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#, interpolation

I am new to ArcGIS and not familiar with it. I want to interpolate heights in a DEM file using ArcGIS? Is it possible?
Actually, I want to write a C# code that will read the height from DEM file for given coordinates, and if the height is missing then I will perform interpolation and return the height. 
I want to use ArcGIS interpolation algorithms instead of writing my own.

Comment: Usually a DEM is already "interpolated", meaning it is a continuous raster surface, what format is yours in? If it's an ascii text file commonly called USGS DEM format or similar all you might need to do is run the *DEM to Grid* or *Ascii to Grid* tools (in the Conversion Tools toolbox) to create an interpolated surface.

Comment: @matt, the DEM file is in USGS DEM format and not already interpolated. I do not want to draw or display it on ArcGIS. I want to read its contents in a C# program and apply interpolation programatically using ArcGIS interpolation algorithms.

Comment: The USGS DEM file format is an interchange format and not designed to be used in place. It's a medium to transfer from one place (program) to another. The process of creating a grid from the .dem file, using the conversion tools, will result in a continuous surface - a model with no gaps (but can include "nodata" cells)  - which you can then run your C# code against. I don't think the ArcGIS API will operate directly against the .dem file.

Comment: @Matt, is it possible to use ArcGIS interpolation functions, if present in its API, to do interpolation against data acquired from the .dem file?  For instance, I'm getting heights from .dem file and if height value is missing against certain coordinates, I can use ArcGIS API to interpolate and return me the missing height.

Comment: @rk01, sorry I don't use the api so can't comment on that part.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to interpolate your dem . dem means digital elevation model . you can interpolate contours or points that have elevation field . you should use **topo to raster** tool in arctoolbox to convert contour to dem .

[topo to raster](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Hydrologically_correct_surfaces%3a_Topo_to_Raster)

Comment: What if I have a missing value in my DEM file?

Comment: you can remove your missing value if you know location of missing value in dem . you can use  extract by mask tool to  extract the region without missing value and remove missing value in dem .

Comment: I need to interpolate to compensate for the missing points. And I need to do that programatically, using C# and ArcGIS API's.